# iOS 8.1 with ZXING error ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, automatic-ref-counting, zxing

I developed a DataMatrix Reader for Android with ZXING, and works fine, now I'm working in the version of iOS, but I have this errors when I want to use the library inside my project:

iOS SDK 8.1 and Library
ZXING: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

I use the COCOAPODS:

platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'ZXingObjC', '~> 3.0'

I implemented the library in my project with Cocoapods, now I want to use in my App like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ZXingObjC.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)scanBarcode:(id)sender {

    CGImageRef imageToDecode;  // Given a CGImage in which we are looking for barcodes

    ZXLuminanceSource *source = [[[ZXCGImageLuminanceSource alloc] initWithCGImage:imageToDecode] autorelease];
    ZXBinaryBitmap *bitmap = [ZXBinaryBitmap binaryBitmapWithBinarizer:[ZXHybridBinarizer binarizerWithSource:source]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    // There are a number of hints we can give to the reader, including
    // possible formats, allowed lengths, and the string encoding.
    ZXDecodeHints *hints = [ZXDecodeHints hints];

    ZXMultiFormatReader *reader = [ZXMultiFormatReader reader];
    ZXResult *result = [reader decode:bitmap
                                hints:hints
                                error:&error];
    if (result) {
        // The coded result as a string. The raw data can be accessed with
        // result.rawBytes and result.length.
        NSString *contents = result.text;

        // The barcode format, such as a QR code or UPC-A
        ZXBarcodeFormat format = result.barcodeFormat;
    } else {
        // Use error to determine why we didn't get a result, such as a barcode
        // not being found, an invalid checksum, or a format inconsistency.
    }
}
@end
```

but I have this error:

> DataMatrixReader/ViewController.m:32:99: ARC forbids explicit message
>   send of 'autorelease'
>
> DataMatrixReader/ViewController.m:32:99: 'autorelease' is unavailable:
>   not available in automatic reference counting mode

concretly in this line:

> ZXLuminanceSource *source = [[[ZXCGImageLuminanceSource alloc]
>   initWithCGImage:imageToDecode] autorelease];

Help from "iamnichols"...and after the change the line:

> ZXLuminanceSource *source = [[[ZXCGImageLuminanceSource alloc]
>   initWithCGImage:imageToDecode] autorelease];
>
> to
>
> ZXLuminanceSource *source = [[ZXCGImageLuminanceSource alloc]
>   initWithCGImage:imageToDecode];

Error:

> : CGBitmapContextGetData: invalid context 0x0. This is a
>   serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an
>   invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation
>   of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>   2014-12-15 12:12:36.122 DataMatrixReader[18838:412778] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'Both dimensions must be greater than 0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102626f35 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00000001022bfbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   DataMatrixReader
>
>   0x0000000100f09507 -[ZXBitMatrix initWithWidth:height:] + 231     3
>
>   DataMatrixReader                    0x0000000100f51b7d
>   -[ZXGlobalHistogramBinarizer blackMatrixWithError:] + 141     4   DataMatrixReader                    0x0000000100f530b0
>   -[ZXHybridBinarizer blackMatrixWithError:] + 816  5   DataMatrixReader                    0x0000000100f068ab -[ZXBinaryBitmap blackMatrixWithError:] + 139    6
>
>   DataMatrixReader                    0x0000000100fa43b2
>   -[ZXQRCodeReader decode:hints:error:] + 130   7   DataMatrixReader                    0x0000000100f63d04 -[ZXMultiFormatReader decodeInternal:error:] + 548
>     8   DataMatrixReader                    0x0000000100f62ade
>   -[ZXMultiFormatReader decode:hints:error:] + 142  9   DataMatrixReader                    0x0000000100ef1df2 -[ViewController scanBarcode:] + 322     10  UIKit
>
>   0x0000000102a148be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
>     11  UIKit                               0x0000000102b1b410
>   -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467   12  UIKit                               0x0000000102b1a7df -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522   13 
>   UIKit                               0x0000000102a5a308 -[UIWindow
>   _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735  14  UIKit                               0x0000000102a5ac33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683     15  UIKit
>
>   0x0000000102a279b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246  16  UIKit
>
>   0x0000000102a34a7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370    17
>   UIKit                               0x0000000102a10103
>   _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961     18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010255c551
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010255241d
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269   20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102551a54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868     21  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000102551486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     22  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000104bc09f0 GSEventRunModal + 161  23  UIKit
>   0x0000000102a13420 UIApplicationMain + 1282   24  DataMatrixReader
>   0x0000000100ef2343 main + 115     25  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00000001058a3145 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Now the question is somebody tried to integrate the ZxingObjC in iOS 8.1?

Comment: Have you actually read the error message?

Comment: Yes, but now I have another after to implement the line to avoid the last error.

Comment: The second error is probably because `imageToDecode` is `NULL`. Did you write this code yourself or have you just copied it off the internet and are just expecting it to work?

Comment: SO is not a debugging service. If you don't know what you are doing here perhaps you need to stop using a third party library

Comment: It's step by step from the Official git from ZXingObjC, and the code is a copy/paste from this site, this is a general problem, I know SO is not a debugging service, but I guess is a place to help the people, and for explain the problem is necesary to paste the logs, in this case in the open source Barcodes SDK's no exist more possibilities to decode DataMatrix in iOS, If I can fix this problem, probably another people in the same problem can fix the problem, and this is the philosophy of SO.

Comment: liamnichols, this code is in a button, but the problem is before, when I try to launch the App, the build failed, Perhaps exist some problem with, iOS 8.1?, the version use in this page is with iOS6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your project is using ARC but ZXING library isn't. In that case go to path 'Target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources' in ZXING library. Double click on each .m file and enter '-fno-objc-arc' in popped dialog box. In this way those files will be excluded from ARC

Comment: This is the way to go if you don't know how to convert the library source to ARC

Comment: @WarrenBurton: Agreed :)... But as ZXING is a third party library, JOANA_Batista would like to avoid making changes in it without understanding the code...I think. So told this way.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did the steps like you commented, but I had this error: clang: error: no such file or directory: 'fno-objc-arc'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: I think the correct flag is like here "-fno-objc-arc" not "fno-objc-arc": put "ZXingObjC" source folder into your project
go to project->Build Phases
select all ZXingObjc files(you can select all at once by pressing shift) then press Enter.
key in "-fno-objc-arc" tell compiler to compile these source code without arc. But anyway I have another error in : DataMatrixReader/Pods/ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC/multi/ZXByQuadrantReader.m:29:1: @synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you project is using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) then you don't need to make `autorelease` calls as it is done for you.

Change

```
ZXLuminanceSource *source = [[[ZXCGImageLuminanceSource alloc] initWithCGImage:imageToDecode] autorelease];
```

to

```
ZXLuminanceSource *source = [[ZXCGImageLuminanceSource alloc] initWithCGImage:imageToDecode];
```

Further information about ARC can be found on the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, now the error disappeared, but when I try to execute in the simulator the code, I have the error I show in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me:

Getting Started in the readme.md didn’t work so I had to do the following steps to make it work.

copy the whole folders into your working project’s sub-folder.
and drag/add ZXingObjC.xcodeproj file to `“<your working project>”`.

make sure tick `create folder references for any added folders` option when prompted.
then, go to your project’s Target > Build Phases

under Target Dependencies, `add ZXingObjC-iOS (ZXingObjC)`

under Link Binary With Libraries, `add libZXingObjC-iOS.a`

under the same category, add the following 6 frameworks

```
AVFoundation.framework

CoreGraphics.framework

CoreMedia.framework

CoreVideo.framework

ImageIO.framework

QuartzCore.framework
```

Source in: http://sagage.com/?p=55

My test in a direct device Iphone 4s were good, perhaps is not the best device to test that, Iphone 4s has not a "AutoFocus" feature, very important for work with this barcodes.

hope this saves your day.